# Why use an intent to create an activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

Folks,

This is a newbie question. I have read a few articles on intents but I am a bit confused on what the main idea behind an intent is when it comes to starting an activity. If I know that I have to create and show an activity, why can't I do something as simple as the following?

```
 MyActivity a = new MyActivity();
 a.show();
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: How are you going to set `Intent Filters`, use `Flags`, and the other things that `Intent`s can do? Sure they could have found other ways to do it still but if you're going to come up with other ways then why not just use an `Intent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intents communicate between activities in an app and between apps.

Your example:

```
MyActivity a = new MyActivity();
a.show();
```

assumes that Android is just objects, so that instantiating an Activity and somehow showing it will make it appear. This isn't the case, though; the Android system does a lot more. The activities in your app are "floating", as it were, within the Android framework. Most of what makes an Activity tick is invisible to you. In particular, the Android-specific thread model and the way that the system communicates with Android components (like Activities) is invisible.

I won't go into most of this, but an added advantage of Intents for starting an Activity is that an Activity can add itself as a candidate for Intents that want to do a specific task. Suppose I have an app that edits images. I can easily make myself discoverable by filtering for Intents that have the action ACTION_EDIT for MIME types that I can handle. This is exactly how Android implements the list of apps that appear when you try do to something with a file.

Answer (score 4):

A activity has a lifecycle and this is managed by the framework. I would say to get an extra hold of the life cycle, Android introduced a set of rules to launch a activity (startActivity). To add-on, Intent is not only to launch your activities. Intents can be used to launch other thirdparty or inbuild views/service/targets. This could be another reason why they introduced intent. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 2):

An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed. It can be used with startActivity to launch an Activity, broadcastIntent to send it to any interested BroadcastReceiver components, and startService(Intent) or bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int) to communicate with a background Service.

An Intent provides a facility for performing late runtime binding between the code in different applications. Its most significant use is in the launching of activities, where it can be thought of as the glue between activities. It is basically a passive data structure holding an abstract description of an action to be performed.

click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

in basic words `Intent` is your **ears** regards to Android device. Your activity can talk to Android through `Intent` and listen on "any change" on your phone.

It's like "grandmother" that sits outdoors next to entrance of big house and listens about all talks, gossips and notify you about.